# How to delete entire row, if blank, in a range?

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I've code to copy a sheet from a workbook into another workbook, it then replaces the copied information with the values.

I need to delete any blank rows in a range in column A. The instruction to delete the empty rows isn't working.

I searched but haven't found any explanation.

```
Private Sub Template1()

    Dim FName4 As String
    Dim NewBook4 As Workbook
    Dim wbNew4 As Workbook
    Dim wks4 As Worksheet
    Dim Release As String
    Dim FPath As String
    Dim RDate As String
    
    FPath = InputBox("Please enter file path to save files to")
    Release = InputBox("Enter release number")
    RDate = InputBox("Enter release date in format yyyymmdd")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    FName4 = RDate & " Release " & Release & " Template" & ".xlsx"
 
    Set NewBook4 = Workbooks.Add
 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=NewBook4.Sheets(1)
 
    For Each wks4 In NewBook4.Worksheets
        With wks4.UsedRange
            .Cells.Copy
            .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Next wks4

    NewBook4.Worksheets("Template").Range("A2:A12").Select

    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp

    NewBook4.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName4, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working". Sometimes blank cells are not actually empty.

Comment: The cells contain formulas that return nothing if certain criteria isn’t met. I then copy and paste values to remove the formulas. Could this be reason the code isn’t working?

Comment: And by not working I mean the line to delete and shift up blank rows isn’t working

Comment: Yes, they will not count as blank.

Comment: Thank you, I can reference true blank cells on another sheet so will try to use that to delete the rows on this sheet

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp

By this:
Selection.Worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp

That should work for you!